# how to change date format 2021-30-06T05:00:00+07:00 in swift?

Tags: swift, time, nsdateformatter

i want to change date format from 2021-30-06T05:00:00+07:00 to get only time with format hh:mm:ss, but i didn't get it.
here is my code i already try

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT+7")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2021-30-06T05:00:00+07:00")

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() 
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)

print(timeStamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `2021-30-06T05:00:00+07:00` is not matching with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`.

Date format should be `yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021-30-06T05:00:00+07:00")

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
print(timeStamp)
```

Output:

```
03:30:00  // This is as per my current timezone.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
print(dateFormatter.string(from: post.createdDate))
```

Use DateFormatter instead of NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let yourDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021-30-06T05:00:00+07:00")

// change to local time zone from your format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let DateString = dateFormatter.string(from: yourDate!)
print(DateString)
```